# CORS config set successfully to google cloud bucket. But CORS header aint added to images uploaded BEFORE settings CORS config to bucket

Tags: image, cors, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I just can't understand why this is, but as the title explains, i applied the following CORS config to my google cloud storage bucket:

```
//this filename: gcs_cors_config.json

[{
  "maxAgeSeconds": 3600, 
  "method": ["*"], 
  "origin": ["*"], 
  "responseHeader": ["*"]
}]
```

using the gsutil command:
`gsutil cors set config/gcs_cors_config.json gs://<bucket_name>`

Now, images uploaded to the bucket AFTER i set this configuration, have the `access-control-allow-origin = *` header as expected
[image]

But, images uploaded BEFORE setting this configuration, DO NOT have the `access-control-allow-origin = *` header.

Now this is a problem for me, because I'm using HTML canvas to do some stuff, and without the CORS header on the images, the canvas is getting tainted and all sorts of issues are happening.

Once again to clarify, the CORS header does get attached to images uploaded AFTER settings the CORS config. But, does not get attached to images uploaded BEFORE setting the CORS config.

Any ideas & help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are those images cached? If so, could you flush that cache?

Comment: @jub0bs i flushed the cache on the browser side. No luck. But could it be that the images are also cached on the cloud storage server side? If so, any idea on how to invalidate that cache? thanks for the response!

Comment: hey @jub0bs you are right! i just checked again, i guess the cache on cloud-storage side got invalidate (because max-age was 3600), so everything is working fine now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so this was a false alarm.

Turns out cloud-storage caches images on its server side as well:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/caching

Which has an age of 1 hour.

So after an hour, the older images also had the `access-control-allow-origin = *` header, and so all works well!

thanks @jub0bs for the suggestion :)